# Limits: Under what conditions can a function be replaced in a limit?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a real-valued function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) $ may be replaced by $f(x_0)$ provided it is continous at $x_o$ is well known, however, I was wondering what one might do (say, to ease the calculation of a limit) when that is not necessarily a case.

Let $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ be continuous on $D(f) \setminus X$, where $|X| \le 1, X \subset D(F)$. Provided $X$ is non-vacuous, call the element $x_0 \in X$.

Say $X \neq \emptyset$ and we wish to calculate $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x)$ (which might not exist). To aide in computation (e.g., to simplify the expression within the limit), one "trick" I thought I could do is to replace say $g(x)$, a possibly complicated function, by any old (possibly simpler) $q(x)$, if $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{g(x)}{q(x)} = 1$.

However, I am disturbed by the fact that when we pick $g(x) = x^3 + 1$ and the "replacement" function $q(x) = x^4 + 1$, locally, they seem to be very different creatures around the origin ($x_0 = 0$). (The fact that they are continuous at $x_0$ is obvious to me, however, provided such a swap were possible, I'd expect it to work even in the case of a fx continous at a point and these two yielded nice counterexamples to my intuition.)

One way around that would be to require $\frac{d(g(x))}{dx} = \frac{d(q(x))}{dx}$ whenever we wanted to perform such a swap, which seems to be quite restrictive. Another possibility that occured to me (though possibly wrong) was to allow such a swap of $g(x)$ and $q(x)$ iff they are both uniformly continuous.

The situation when/if such a swap is possible remains something of a puzzle to me, so I'd welcome any insights.

Thanks!